# Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1280; errors: 1

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load some data from Google Sheets to Big Query. It's 5 sheets. I am using gapps scripts to do it.

I am trying to loading very same data as I was loading last week the problem is that all the upload jobs are failing now, for every single sheet.

I am getting:
*Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1280; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.*

When I look in CLI, I see :*-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'*

The problem is that my doc has 0 newline characters. I am also getting the "1280" number for 5 various sheets I am trying to upload and NONE of them has 1280 rows

The second column is the name of the sheet being uploaded. All getting the same error all of the sudden:
[image]

Big Query is quite powerful but this random crap is totally killing the experience.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: If it's an option, I'd suggest putting your data into a single CSV and uploading this, as I've found the CSV uploader to be much more robust.

Comment: not an option, unfortunately, different columns on different sheets...

What's more I see this problem happening across all my files now which still worked OK in the morning.

Comment: it's hard to reproduce the question as stated - can you show us any sample sheet, and the script code that is failing?

Comment: Okay guys... So this is a weird one. Something had changed in our admin console of Gapps and we are no longer able to share the sheets via public links.

Since my gapps script was using public links to upload to BQ, it would try to always upload the "login screen", hence all the errors would be row 1280 since the screen is always the same...

So overall, I really has not changed anything but our deus ex machina has changed something...